# Mocha: Test pass after summary of all tests in suite

Tags: javascript, mocha.js

This is one of mine test classes

```html
const fs = require('fs');
const chai = require('chai');
const config = require('../config');
const request = require('supertest')(config.url);
const assert = chai.assert;
require('mocha');



var log4js = require('log4js');
var logger = log4js.getLogger('08_order'); 
log4js.configure({
  appenders: {
    out:{ type: 'console' },
    app:{ type: 'file', filename: 'logs/log.log' }
  },
  categories: {
    default: { appenders: [ 'out', 'app' ], level: 'info' }
  }
})




var dineInOrderDetails=[];
var deliveryOrderDetails=[];




describe('order', function() {
  this.timeout(10000);



   it('should submit simple product order for dine in', function(done) {
    request
      .post('/rest/v2/order/submit')
      .set(config.headers)
      .set('Authorization', 'Bearer ' + auth_token) 
      //.set('Accept', 'application/json')  
      .send(
        {  
          "restaurantId":dineInRestaurantId,
          "deliveryAddress":{  
             "city":dineInRestaurantCity,
             "street":dineInRestaurantStreet,
             "houseNumber":dineInRestaurantStreetNo,
             "lat":dineInRestaurantGeoLat,
             "lng":dineInRestaurantGeoLng,
             "inDeliveryZone":true
       
          },
          "deliveryType":"DINE_IN",
          "deliveryTime":"14:24",
          "paymentType":"CARD_DEL",
          "customer":{  
             "phoneNumber":"530323370",
             "firstName":"Imie",
             "emailAddress":"x@x.pl",
             "customerName":"Imie"
          },
          "agreements":{  
             "acceptTerms":true,
             "acceptDataProcessingAgreement":true
          },
          "basket":{  
             "basketLines":[  
                {  
                   "uuid":"uuid",
                   "quantity":2,
                   "product":{  
                      "id": randomAvailableSimpleProductIdForDineIn
                   }
                }
             ]
          }
       } 
      )
      .end(function(err,res){
        logger.info(config.logToConsole(res.request.url,res.request._data));
        assert.equal(res.status,200);
        assert.containsAllKeys(res.body,['uuid','totalGross','totalAmount','orderNo','orderStatus','deliveryTime']);
        logger.info('uuid: ',res.body.uuid);
        dineInOrderDetails[0]=res.body.uuid;
        dineInOrderDetails[1]=res.body.totalGross;
        dineInOrderDetails[2]=res.body.totalAmount;
        done(err);
      });    
   });



   it('should return details of last order', function(done) {
    tempUrl="/rest/v1/user/orders/"+dineInOrderDetails[0];
    request 
      .get(tempUrl)
      .set(config.headers)
      .set('Authorization', 'Bearer ' + auth_token)
      .end(function(err,res){
        logger.info(config.logToConsole(res.request.url,res.request._data));
        assert.equal(res.status,200);
        assert.equal(res.body.order.uuid, dineInOrderDetails[0]);
        assert.equal(res.body.order.totalGross, dineInOrderDetails[1]);
        assert.equal(res.body.order.totalAmount, dineInOrderDetails[2]);
        done(err);
      });        
   });



   it('should return recent orders', function(done) {
    request 
      .get("/rest/v1/user/orders")
      .set(config.headers)
      .set('Authorization', 'Bearer ' + auth_token)
      .end(function(err,res){
        logger.info(config.logToConsole(res.request.url));
        assert.equal(res.status,200);
        assert.isArray(res.body.orders);
        assert.containsAllKeys(res.body.orders[0],'uuid','totalGross','totalAmount','cellPhone','deliveryTime','currency','addedAtDate',
          'isClaim','isFavourite','status','orderNumber','restaurant','zipCode');
        done(err);
      });        
   });

//done(err);
});
```

Test are running locally with docker, also i use mailhog to receive sms and mails.
In most cases if i run tests, first test: 'should submit simple product order for dine in' is waiting for 10 sec timeout, then fail, in console i receive fail summary:

> 2) order
>          should submit simple product order for dine in:
>        Error: Timeout of 10000ms exceeded. For async tests and hooks, ensure "done()" is called; if returning a Promise, ensure it resolves.
>   (C:\dockerApi\test\08_order.js)

and after fail summary in console i receive info that this case is passed with properly sent body. Why i receive pass info after finishing all tests?

Do you have problem like this?

Comment: Warning saying that promise is not resolved or done is not being called. Try to debug using console.log()

Comment: Are you able to do the same request using e.g. `curl`?